# Joining two DataFrames and appending where not exists

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two DataFrames. One is a MasterList, the other is an InsertList

MasterList:

```
+--------+--------+
|  ttm_id|audit_id|
+--------+--------+
|       1|      10|
|      15|      10|
+--------+--------+
```

InsertList:

```
+--------+--------+
|  ttm_id|audit_id|
+--------+--------+
|       1|      10|
|      15|       9|
+--------+--------+
```

In Scala, how do I join two DataFrames but only append to the new DataFrame records

```sql
WHERE MasterList.ttm_id = InsertList.ttm_id AND
      MasterList.audit_id != InsertList.audit_id
```

-

ExpectedOutput:

```
+--------+--------+
|  ttm_id|audit_id|
+--------+--------+
|       1|      10|
|      15|      10|
|      15|       9|
+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd anti join (`NOT IN`) by both columns and `union`

```
val masterList = Seq((1, 10), (15, 10)).toDF("ttm_id", "audit_id")
val insertList = Seq((1, 10), (15, 9)).toDF("ttm_id", "audit_id")

insertList
    .join(masterList, Seq("ttm_id", "audit_id"), "leftanti")
    .union(masterList)
    .show
// +------+--------+
// |ttm_id|audit_id|
// +------+--------+
// |    15|       9|
// |     1|      10|
// |    15|      10|
// +------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to *merge* *rows* from `insertList` *dataFrame* that are not in `masterList` *dataFrame*. This can be achived using `except` function

```
insertList.except(masterList)
```

And you just use `union` function merge both *dataFrames* as

```
masterList.union(insertList.except(masterList))
```

You should get what you desire as

```
+------+--------+
|ttm_id|audit_id|
+------+--------+
|1     |10      |
|15    |10      |
|15    |9       |
+------+--------+
```